# Map not showing in react leaf­let

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3, react-leaflet-v4

Why the map is not displayed in react leaflet?

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";


    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}>
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed adding a style sheet to `MapContainer`, and its height is 0 now. You should add the style `style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}` to the `MapContainer`, have a look at the code below:

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
        zoom={13}
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        fadeAnimation={true}
        markerZoomAnimation={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cherry-s5mb4p?file=/src/App.js:0-735

Comment: The style attribute should be added to official documentation example. This worked for my Create-React-App. Thanks!